# FancyBox iFrame closes when going back in history

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to use FancyBox 2 in iframe mode to implement modal edit dialogs. Once the iframe with the edit form is closed, I want to be able to run specific code to perform actions in the parent window, such as reload the content. The form in the iframe is using regular form posts, rather than ajax and can take multiple submissions, because of the server-side validation.

In order to execute my code in the main page after the dialog is closed, I populate the FancyBox afterClose property.

**Problem:**
If I simply close the iframe after successful submission/validation of the form data, the iframe closes and the afterClose code gets executed properly, as expected. The problem is that by then the window history gets corrupted with additional entries. This means that, once the iframe is closed I need to click the back button multiple times (equal to the number of submissions in the iframe) to go back to the page before the one that hosted the iframe.

To work around this I tried keeping track of the history depth in the iframe and execute window.history.go(-depth), before executing parent.$.fancybox.close() to close the iframe. This takes care of the history issue, but prevents the afterClose code from being executed. Some experimentation indicated that going back in history to the original iframe page kills FancyBox in a way that prevents afterClose from running (the parent.$.fancybox.close() is not even executed).

**Questions:**
Does anybody know why the FancyBox iframe get destroyed when the back button is pressed enough times to reach the original page loaded in the iframe? Can this be prevented?
Is there a different way to rewind the iFrame history when the FancyBox iFrame is closed?

**Example:**
The problem is illustrated **[in this page](http://www.foxweb.com/temp/FancyBoxMain.html)**. The same source is below:

FancyBoxMain.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Main</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popup() {
            var options = {
                type: 'iframe',
                href: 'FancyBoxPopup.html',
                height: 250,
                modal: true,
                autoSize: false,
                afterClose: function () { alert('Executing afterClose.'); }
            };
            $.fancybox.open(options);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="popup();" value="Popup"/>
</body>
</html>
```

FancyBoxPopup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
        var depth;

        $(function() {
            var pos = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
            depth = pos == -1 ? 0 : parseInt(window.location.href.substr(pos + 1));
            $('#depth').text(depth);
            url = pos == -1 ? window.location.href : window.location.href.substr(0, pos);
            if (depth > 0) {
                $('#actions').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <div>
            Depth:
            <span id="depth"></span>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href = '?' + (depth + 1).toString();" />
        </div>
        <div id="actions" style=" display: none;padding: 0; margin: 0;">
            <input type="button" value="Close FancyBox" onclick="parent.$.fancybox.close();"/>
            <input type="button" value="Rewind History, before closing FancyBox" onclick="history.go(-depth); parent.$.fancybox.close();"/>
            <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back();" />
            <div>Bad behavior:
                <ul>
                    <li>Simply closing FancyBox allows the afterClose handler to run. The problem is that when depth > 0, the iFrame's history is kept, breaking correct functionality of the browser's back button.</li>
                    <li>Rewinding history back to 0 depth kills FancyBox, preventing the afterClose handler from firing. You can see this step-by-step by clicking the back button.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```